# TensorFlow custom loss: "No gradients provided for any variable" error

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

I want to implement a loss, so I wrote the following function based on spearman correlation

`

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.losses import Loss
class Spearman(Loss):
    def call(self, target, pred):
        pred = tf.argsort(pred, axis=0)
        target = tf.argsort(target, axis=0)
        pred = pred - tf.reduce_mean(pred)
        pred = tf.cast(pred, tf.float32)
        target = tf.cast(target, tf.float32)
        pred = pred / (tf.norm(pred)+0.01)
        target = target - tf.reduce_mean(target)
        target = target / (tf.norm(target)+0.01)
        return -tf.reduce_sum(pred * target)
```

`

i was inspired by the method of pytorch with differentiable sort but i have no gradient with tensorflolw

Comment: cast is not differentiable, and might not even be needed.

Comment: `argsort` is certainly not differentiable, though.